# React.js:Why does this event run before calling?

Tags: reactjs, function, components

in this code, insertVariable() function run before calling Which leads to an error in my program. But If I don`t define any parameter for this function, my code works fine

```
 class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      };
    insertVariable = actionType => {
    
    };
        
        render(){
        return(
        <div>
         <Button
           key="btnDone"
           onClick={this.insertVariable('done')}
         >
           Done
         </Button>,
         <Button
           key="btnAdd"
           type="primary"
           onClick={this.insertVariable('add')}
         >
           Add
         </Button>
        </div>
        )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because *you're calling it*. `this.insertVariable('done')` is calling the method with the value `'done'`, and you're passing the *result* as the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling it in the onClick function. Change it to

```
onClick={()=>this.insertVariable('add')}
```